# Remove first level xml (and namespace) tag regex

Tags: regex, xml

Lets say I have the following XML

```
<Monkey xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey.com/monkeynamespace">
 <foodType>
  <vegtables>
   <carrots>1</carrots>
  </vegtables>
 <foodType>   
</Monkey>
```

Now the service im using already has the root level element and name space. so I really just need:

```
 <foodType>
  <vegtables>
   <carrots>1</carrots>
  </vegtables>
 <foodType>
```

Is there a regex I can use that generically removes both the top level opening and closing tags? By generic I mean that it doesn't have to start with the type Monkey.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the following regex:

`^<[^>]+>(.*)<\/\w+>$`

and replace with the first captured group `\1` or `$1`

### Demo